# Error "useradd: group '100' does not exist"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I get the above mentioned error when I try to add a user.

By trying

`sudo useradd -u 1200 -g test -c 'studente' student`

or

`sudo useradd anyuser`

I get

```
useradd: group '100' does not exist
useradd: the GROUP= configuration in /etc/default/useradd will be ignored
```

Content of `/etc/default/useradd` is

```
# useradd defaults file
GROUP=100
HOME=/home
INACTIVE=-1
EXPIRE=
SHELL=/bin/bash
SKEL=/etc/skel
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=yes
```

I must have messed up somewhere by creating, modifying and deleting users and groups but I don't know where.

Comment: do i have to make one? and where did it go? i deleted it somehow if there has to be one?

Comment: What distribution are you using? I can give you the exact command to create the necessary group if I know the distribution and version. But it is probably `groupadd -g 100 users` but before you do that try `grep :100: /etc/group-`

Comment: I am using fedora 30

Comment: Alright. On Fedora, group `100` is `users`. All you need to do is `groupadd -g 100 users`.

Comment: @accdias aah thank you! I must have deleted users group. I didnt know the 'importance' of this group.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad to help you. Next time you have a question about operating system, try to use the right forum. StackOverflow is dedicated to programming questions only. :-)

Comment: If you could answer the question with little clarification too please. Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have deleted the group `100` by accident.

On Fedora, group ID `100` is `users`. To solve that problem, all you have to do is create the group again:

```sh
groupadd -g 100 users
```

For more information about `groupadd` use `man groupadd`.

For more information about users and groups, check Fedora documentation [Managing Users and Groups](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/system-administrators-guide/basic-system-configuration/Managing_Users_and_Groups/).